# Handler for ActionBar MenuButton click

Tags: java, android, button, menu, onclick

Even after a long search on this subject I came to no result. So I want to ask here.

In my Android application, I try to set a onClick listener for the menu button in the upper right corner (on the actionbar). When the button is pressed, the NavigationDrawer should open. (I have seen this in an app. Unfortunately, I do not know how this app is called.) I do not want to open the menu.

I have already tried:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:onClick="showdrawer">
    <item />
</menu>
```

with

```
public void showdrawer(View v) {
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
}
```

...but nothing happens when I press the button.
Is there a way to implement this?

I would be very grateful for help.

Answer (score 0):

> In my Android application, I try to set a onClick listener for the menu button in the upper right corner (on the actionbar).

First, there is not necessarily a "menu button in the upper right corner (on the actionbar)" on all devices, when using the stock action bar implementation. It will depend upon API level of the device and whether the device has an off-screen MENU key.

Second, that is for the overflow. Please leave it alone.

Third, you have no direct access to that button anyway.

> When the button is pressed, the NavigationDrawer should open

The navigation drawer is usually opened by tapping on the *left* side of the action bar, on the app icon, particularly when it has the "mini-hamburger" on the left edge. That is handled for you [via `ActionBarDrawerToggle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html), if you are using `DrawerLayout` for the navigation drawer.

It is possible to have a right-hand drawer as well, though I seem to recall Google advocating that more for contextual operations. They do not cover this in the written design guidelines, but I seem to recall seeing it on an Android Design in Action video. For that, you might use your own regular action item in the action bar as a trigger, if the right-hand drawer is for activity-level contextual operations.